# Vulnerabilties Pleks VS cPanel

Tags: web-services, security, cpanel, plesk, whm

As a web hosting reseller i have a question: Pleks or cPanel

I mean, who is more secure ? With less hack vulnerabilities ? Some people tell me Plesk is more secure and with cPanel you have a lot of security breach.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you about [Plesk](https://www.plesk.com/), which is focused on security and provides a lot of solutions, such as ModSecurity, Fail2Ban, Security Advisor, out of the box to prevent your server, websites, mail, etc. from hacking.
Also Plesk has extension catalog with [security extensions](https://www.plesk.com/extensions/category/security/) to secure your server and its services more.
WordPress toolkit, which is available in Plesk, allows you to secure WordPress installations.
Let's Encrypt extension will allow you to install free SSL Certificates on your websites.
With the help of Package Update Manager Plesk makes sure that all latest OS updates are installed.

Try Plesk [for free](https://page.plesk.com/plesk-onyx-free-download) and check it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you were hoping to hear more than just from people that work for the companies involved, but I can similarly answer for cPanel.

[cPanel](https://cpanel.net) is incredibly secure out of the box, and comes with the backing of a massive community of plugin developers and integrators, but we also allow administrators to make their own decisions about their configuration. The drawback for that is that some administrators make their server less secure, without fully understanding the consequences.

If you have any questions at all about cPanel, please do let me know, or you can try it for free. Any new cPanel server that's built is automatically issued a trial license, so you can try it for free for 15 days.

Comment: cPanel is not incredibly secured out of the box. It needs some proper customization in order to be really secure. But it's a really nice panel and I personally prefer it over plesk

Answer (score 0):

Both cPanel and Plesk have their pro(s) and con(s). While I like cPanel more (probably because I had to chance to use it more) there are some really nice default features in Plesk that make it, let's say, more attractive. One of them would be installing nginx and being able to run it as a standalone server for specific sites and not as a reverse proxy for apache. Same behaviour can be achieved on cPanel servers with nginxcp plugin (which is not free but the price is decent $5/month).

Both cPanel and plesk have mod_security, firewalls and a ton of other features. If you ask me, cPanel is more user friendly for the regular user while Plesk seems to be a little bit complicated sometimes. Another big difference will be that cPanel can be only installed on CentOS systems while Plesk can be installed on CentOS, Debian etc. If you ask me I was preferring cPanel since it was running really smooth with CloudLinux and configuring it properly resulted in a really secure server. As far as I know CloudLinux works on Plesk too now so...

It's really hard to say which one of them is more secure. It all depends on how you configure them both. I would say to try them both (both offer free trial licenses for a limited amount of time: cPanel 15 days, Plesk 30 days if I'm not wrong) and see which one you like best.

Oh, last but not least, cPanel staff provides really high tech support (which is included with the license). I think they are way ahead of Plesk at providing support for their customers (at least from my experience).